# Mounting new HDD, error: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock, missing codepage or helper program or other error

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, badblocks

Recentely I've installed a new HDD in my system. After making a partition with Gparted, mounting it to a folder I made called /mnt/media and writing the necessary line in /etc/fstab I get the following message after sudo mount /mnt/media:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

The fstab line:

```
UUID=f179af91-fab5-4632-9fe7-295262edf2ed /mnt/media ext4 default,user,rw,nofail,exec 0 0
```

The Gparted info:

[image: Screenshot of Gparted]

What might cause this error and how to fix it? I've already checked for the usual things (fs type, mounting, fsck etc). I want to rule out if my new HDD is the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant line from your fstab file. How exactly did you make "a file" called /mnt/media? (it should be a directory)

Comment: I have included the screenshot of fstab. Its the last line. My mistake about the file, its a folder I made with the command mkdir

Comment: Thanks - I believe the first option should be `defaults` (plural) rather than `default`

Comment: @steeldriver You are right. I checked online, default doesn't exist. Strange, since I just checked my fstab and one of the mounts had default instead of defaults and has worked fine for years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `default` to `defaults`.

For future reference, just make a code / quote block with you fstab contents and if you really need to add images, embed them.

Also, /mnt/media should be a directory not a file.